# how to hold data in editbox when go to next page, the back again, the data still there? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[The flow of the apps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1D3D.png)

This example that I want to achieve in my program.
User enter number in editbox on page 1, note here he hasn't saved the number then go to next page. There no worry for him to go back to the previous page because the data he enters halfway still there.
The question is what makes or method apply to the program that can hold the data even though the page is refresh?

```
public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnB1,btnC3,btnD;
TextView TB1total, TC3Total, TDtotal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
    btnB1 = findViewById(R.id.B1detail);
    btnC3 = findViewById(R.id.C3detail);
    btnD = findViewById(R.id.D_Detail);

    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.CurDateTime);
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM MM-dd -yyyy h:mm a");
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);
    tv.setText(dateString);


    Intent intent4 = getIntent();
    String text = intent4.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    TextView EmpId2 =findViewById(R.id.Re_EmpId);
    EmpId2.setText(text);

    final EditText EtText;
    final DatePickerDialog[] shiftDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog[1];
    EtText= findViewById(R.id.ShiftDate);

    EtText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view){
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDAy = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            shiftDatePicker[0] = new DatePickerDialog(Homepage.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                   EtText.setText(dayOfMonth+ "/"+ monthOfYear+ "/" + year);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth , mDAy);
            shiftDatePicker[0].show();
        }
    });


    final EditText EtTime;
    EtTime = findViewById(R.id.ShiftTime);
    EtTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar mCurTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mCurTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mCurTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Homepage.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    EtTime.setText(selectedHour+":"+selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour,minute,true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
        }
    });

   


    final EditText ReWBreak, ReSemiFi;
    Button CalTotal;
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, DelTotal;

    ReWBreak = findViewById(R.id.ReWBreak);
    ReSemiFi = findViewById(R.id.ReSemiFi);
    CalTotal = findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
    DelTotal = findViewById(R.id.ReTotalQ);

    CalTotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int W1 = Integer.parseInt(ReWBreak.getText().toString());
            int W2 = Integer.parseInt(ReSemiFi.getText().toString());
            int TotalDel = W1+W2;

        }
    });
btnB1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Homepage.this, B1.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent1,1);
    }
});
btnC3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Homepage.this, C3.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent2, 2);
    }
});
btnD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(Homepage.this, D.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent3, 3);
    }
});
    Intent intent5 = getIntent();
    String text1 = intent5.getStringExtra("B1RESULT");
    TextView B1Result =findViewById(R.id.ReTotalB1);
    B1Result.setText(text1);

    Intent intent6 = getIntent();
    String text2 = intent6.getStringExtra("C3RESULT");
    TextView C3Result =findViewById(R.id.ReTotalC3);
    C3Result.setText(text2);
}
```

This is page1 code, Homepage.class

```
public class B1 extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b1);

    Button B1Back,SubmitB1;

    final TextView B1result;
    final EditText B1Input1,B1Input2,B1Input3,B1Input4,B1Input5,B1Input6,B1Input7,B1Input8,B1Input9,B1Input10,B1Input11,B1Input12,B1Input13,B1Input14,B1Input15,
            B1Input16,B1Input17,B1Input18,B1Input19,B1Input20,B1Input21,B1Input22,B1Input23,B1Input24;


    B1Input1=findViewById(R.id.Ed_chip);
    B1Input2=findViewById(R.id.Stain);
    B1Input3=findViewById(R.id.BSF_Stain);
    B1Input4=findViewById(R.id.FS_Bright);
    B1Input5=findViewById(R.id.BS_Bright);
    B1Input6=findViewById(R.id.Colour_Con);
    B1Input7=findViewById(R.id.BS_Paste);
    B1Input8=findViewById(R.id.FS_Paste);
    B1Input9=findViewById(R.id.BS_BrokenFi);
    B1Input10=findViewById(R.id.FS_BrokeFi);
    B1Input11=findViewById(R.id.Poor_print);
    B1Input12=findViewById(R.id.Finger_Node);
    B1Input13=findViewById(R.id.BS_ThickFin);
    B1Input14=findViewById(R.id.FS_ThickFin);
    B1Input15=findViewById(R.id.BSF_SPot);
    B1Input16=findViewById(R.id.BSF_Missing);
    B1Input17=findViewById(R.id.BSF_Scratch);
    B1Input18=findViewById(R.id.FS_Scratch);
    B1Input19=findViewById(R.id.FS_Shifted);
    B1Input20=findViewById(R.id.BS_Shifted);
    B1Input21=findViewById(R.id.BSE_Missing);
    B1Input22=findViewById(R.id.BSE_Shift);
    B1Input23=findViewById(R.id.LowETA);
    B1Input24=findViewById(R.id.OtherB1);
    B1result=findViewById(R.id.TotalB1);
    SubmitB1 =findViewById(R.id.B1Submit);
    B1Back = findViewById( R.id.BackB1);

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if(!B1Input1.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input2.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input3.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input4.getText().toString().equals("")&&
            !B1Input5.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input6.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input6.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input7.getText().toString().equals("")&&
            !B1Input8.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input9.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input10.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input11.getText().toString().equals("")&&
            !B1Input12.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input13.getText().toString().equals("") && !B1Input14.getText().toString().equals("") &&!B1Input15.getText().toString().equals("")&&
            !B1Input16.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input17.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input18.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input19.getText().toString().equals("")&&
            !B1Input20.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input21.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input22.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input23.getText().toString().equals("")&&!B1Input24.getText().toString().equals(""))
         {
             int num1 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input1.getText().toString());
             int num2 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input2.getText().toString());
             int num3 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input3.getText().toString());
             int num4 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input4.getText().toString());
             int num5 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input5.getText().toString());
             int num6 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input6.getText().toString());
             int num7 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input7.getText().toString());
             int num8 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input8.getText().toString());
             int num9 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input9.getText().toString());
             int num10 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input10.getText().toString());
             int num11= Integer.parseInt(B1Input11.getText().toString());
             int num12 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input12.getText().toString());
             int num13 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input13.getText().toString());
             int num14 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input14.getText().toString());
             int num15 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input15.getText().toString());
             int num16 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input16.getText().toString());
             int num17= Integer.parseInt(B1Input17.getText().toString());
             int num18 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input18.getText().toString());
             int num19 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input19.getText().toString());
             int num20 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input20.getText().toString());
             int num21 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input21.getText().toString());
             int num22 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input22.getText().toString());
             int num23 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input23.getText().toString());
             int num24 = Integer.parseInt(B1Input24.getText().toString());
             int sum= num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10+num11+num12+num13+num14
                     +num15+num16+num17+num18+num19+num20+num21+num22+num23+num24;
             B1result.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        }

    };

    B1Input1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input4.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input5.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input6.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input7.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input8.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input9.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input10.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input11.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input12.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input13.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input14.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input15.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input16.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input17.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input18.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input19.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input20.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input21.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input22.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input23.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    B1Input24.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);




    SubmitB1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(B1Input1.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input2.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input3.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input4.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input5.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input6.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input7.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input8.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input9.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input10.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input11.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input12.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input13.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input14.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input15.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input16.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input17.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input18.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input19.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input20.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input21.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input22.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input23.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(B1Input24.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There something missing, please check again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Submit success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    B1Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String b1result = B1result.getText().toString();
            Intent B1Total = new Intent(B1.this,Homepage.class);
            B1Total.putExtra("B1RESULT",b1result);
            startActivity(B1Total);
            finish();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior, you don't need to do anything at all for this to happen.

EDIT

The reason it doesn't work for you is because of this part in B1:

```
 B1Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String b1result = B1result.getText().toString();
            Intent B1Total = new Intent(B1.this,Homepage.class);
            B1Total.putExtra("B1RESULT",b1result);
            startActivity(B1Total);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Here you are creating a new Intent, and starting a **new** activity instead of returning to the already created activity you came from.

Instead, you should simply call `finish()` which will finish `B1` activity, and return you to `Homepage`

Specifically in this case, you are not only returning to `Homepage`, but you also send a result from `B1`. This is done differently when using `finish()`, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: but mine is does not show default behavior, how should i tackle this. I'll show my codes.

Comment: @XiaoProgrammer also check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63423471/5313608) to a question related to returning result from activities, with a detailed explanation on how to do it

Comment: Thank you so much Tal. It is really helping me solve my program's problem.